# Frozen pane gets partially cropped when exporting to PDF

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I'm exporting from an excel range with frozen pane at the top to a PDF file through VBA.
In my Page Layout, Width is set to 1 page, and Height is on Automatic.
For some reason though, the two first rows of my frozen pane get cropped in all pages of PDF but the first one.

First page:
[image: Top of the frist page of my PDF file]

Other pages:
[image: Top of all other pages of my PDF file]

Here is the code used to export (pretty straightforward):

```
lastRow = getLastRow(targetWksht) 'targetWksht is well defined elsewhere
lastCol = getLastCol(targetWksht)

With targetWksht.Range(targetWksht.Cells(1, 1), targetWksht.Cells(lastRow, lastCol))
    .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                         fileName:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & fileName, _ 'fileName is defined elsewhere
                         Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                         IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                         IgnorePrintAreas:=True, _
                         OpenAfterPublish:=True
End With
```

It might be something stupid, but do you know where it may come from and how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where it came from.
The frozen pane was selected as page title, but for some reason not all rows in this title were supposed to be repeated in following pages.

Therefore, the title appeared complete in the first page, but only partial in other ones.

To solve the problem, if you encounter it, follow this:
In Excel, go to Page Layout > Page Setup > Print Titles. You will have Print Area, which is the title, and below, Rows to repeat at top. 
Make sure that all rows from your title are selected. For some reason my default parameter started at 3 instead of 1, setting it at 1 solved the problem.

NB: It also works for columns at left.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$worksheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 9999` instead of automatic or set your margins with code.

Comment: Same result, next pages get cropped at the top. It looks like to me that the two first rows simply do not go through the export, instead of a margins issue...